# Match a group of words using regex

Tags: regex

I have a long string in the format:

```
' Random Key         : Random Value\n Random Long Key     : Random Long Value\n...'
```

and so on.
I am trying to change it to

```
Random Value:Random Key, Random Long Value:Random Long Key,...
```

by using regex. I can match a single word by

```
\w+
```

but in order to match more than one word i am doing

```
\w+(\s\w+)*
```

but that's not giving me the wanted result.

Comment: Example would be helpful.

Comment: Which programming language do you happen to use?

Answer (score 0):

You might use this piece of code to find the key-value pairs:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var regex = new Regex(@"\s*(?<key>(\w+\s?\w+)*)\s*:\s*(?<val>(\w+\s?\w+))\s*");
        var input = @" Key         : Value\n Long Key     : Long Value\n...";
        Console.WriteLine(regex.Replace(input, "${key}:${val}").Replace("\\n", ", "));
    }
}
```

The trick is to match "any number of (at least one word character, an optional space, and at least another word character)", which finds keys for us with spaces. The shortest no-space key is two characters though.

I admit that the escaped line breaks aren't replaced by a regex, but this way both expression and code are fairly simple.

Comment: my problem is some keys do contain spaces

Comment: @user6068049 OK, I changed the regex. I presumes C# as a programming language. The regex syntax might be slightly different on another platform.

Answer (score 0):

If your `\n` really is part of the string you can match and replace it like this:

```
/(?:\s*([^\\]+?)\s*:\s*([^\\]+?)\s*)+\\n/g
```

and substitute it with

```
$1:$2,
```

[See Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nV7tF8/1).

If you have it line-by-line then its easier because you can use multiline matching:

```
/^\s*(.+?)\s*:\s*(.+?)\s*$/mg
```

and also substitute it with

```
$1:$2,
```

[See Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oP1vX0/1).

Answer (score 0):

None of the other answers worked fully for me, as they kept matching the space after the final word. the regex that worked as intended is

`(\w+(?:\s\w+)*)`